# Docker image error The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure on client web-application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssl, identityserver4, x509certificate2

I always get the following error on my client WebApp (running as separate Linux docker image port 4443):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://host.docker.internal:8443/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://host.docker.internal:8443/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Which is connected to my IdentityServer4 (running as separate Linux docker image port 4444).
In the IS4 Startup.cs I create the certificate which the following code:

```
...
var idpUri = configuration["AppConfig:IdentityProviderUrl"];
var dnsName = new Uri(idpUri).DnsSafeHost;
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"certificate.pfx")));
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
      options.IssuerUri = idpUri;
   }).AddSigningCredential(cert); //A self-signed PFX certificate located in the root of the IS4 and also copied in de client app used for Kestrel cert.
...
```

In my client WebApp I inserted the following code to set the authority:

```
  string identityProviderUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppConfig:IdentityProviderUrl");
  services.AddHttpClient(AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_CLIENT_NAME, client => {
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(identityProviderUrl);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
  });
  services.AddAuthentication("Bearer") 
     .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options => { //NOTE: I don't know if this is needed
            options.Authority = identityProviderUrl;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateAudience = false
         };
      });
   services.AddAuthentication(options => {
      options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   }).AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
         options.Authority = identityProviderUrl;
         options.ClientId = oidcClientId;
         options.ClientSecret = oidcClientSecret;
         ...
      });
```

I think there is something wrong which the certificate I'm creating which are not on both docker images. But the Docker containers are running both with HTTPS, else the won't start at all. What am I missing here?

Let's do it by LetsEncrypt as suggested in the comment below.
I download and run this project (src:https://github.com/PKISharp/ACMESharpCore/tree/master/src/examples/ACMECLI)
With the following properties set:

```
public string CaName { get; } = Constants.LetsEncryptStagingName;
public IEnumerable<string> Email { get; } = new string[] { "xxx@gmail.com" };
public bool AcceptTos { get; } = true;
public IEnumerable<string> Dns { get; } = new string[] { "xxx.duckdns.org" };
public (bool enabled, int? timeout) WaitForAuthz { get; } = (true, 300);
public bool Finalize { get; } = true;
public string ExportPfx { get; } = @"c:\tmp\certificate.pfx";
public string ExportPfxPassword { get; } = " ";
```

But it is still pending, a few days already. When it comes valid I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a self-signed certificate for HTTPS, instead get a real certificate or you have to add the certificate to the client trusted certificate store.

The problem is that the client does not trust the certificate it received when trying to establish a secure channel.

Using HTTPS internally and properly is best practice between containers.

To support HTTPS in ASP.NET Core , see this article:

- [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Today i also popular to get your certificates form [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Using them lets you automate the creation of the certificates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I love best practices. 
What do you suggest I change to get it to work? 
And what do you mean with HTTPS internally and properly, you mean that certificate what Kestrel is using to support HTTPS? Can you give examples?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I read this article Enforce HTTPS. I did that app.UseHttpsRedirection part already. What I think it does redirect to HTTPS when I type a HTTP url. 
But I don't see how this fix my certificate issue and using this .AddSigningCredential(cert) part. Or can I get rid of this?
I have looked to that LetsEncrypt, but how do I implement this correctly. I had a example here: https://github.com/Carlos-Carreno-Berlanga/TestLetsEncrypt/tree/master/TestLetsEncrypt.
But it seems to have errors when running it. I attached the error in my post.
Can you help me here?

Comment: When I generate certificates I use the https://github.com/PKISharp/ACMESharpCore library, the CLI example in the /src/examples/ACMECLI have worked fine for me. In other projects I have used https://www.naturalborncoder.com/linux/2021/01/27/how-to-setup-lets-encrypt-for-apache-on-windows/ .

Comment: Also, AddSigningCredential is not about HTTPS, its about how to sign the JWT tokens

Comment: Thanks for the update. So when I'm understand you correctly. 
1) This error message comes because the certificate is invalid and not trusted by the 2 docker container which runs Kestrel on my local docker host and needs a valid certificate to talk with tokens between the 2 webapps? 
And is caused by the Kestrel invalid certificate?
2) And you renew each 90 days that LetsEncrypt certificate by running this CLI project and push it to your projects. Am I understand you correclty?  
3) Has the error nothing to do with this .AddSigningCredential()?

Comment: Hi, I saw this documentation also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0#get-started. 
Do you think I can use this approch to get ride of this SSL certifcate error on the docker container to override this?
Because when I run this CLI it get always status of pending for a couple of hours now.

Comment: to do it properly, you should get a real certificate and lean how to work with them. Overriding or disabling SSL warning is the wrong approach..   Step #1 I would od is to create a simple hello-world app, using certs and get that to work.

Comment: I know, you're right. I can create a self-signed certificate and use that locally, that works. But I tried to get a valid CA certificate from LetsEncrypt with that ACMECLI tool. But that isn't working out-of-the-box. I needed at some points to walk with the debugger through the code to let it generate the PFX. Some timing issues I think. But I have create one. I wrote down my properties I set in above post. And creating a TXT record should have only the {cert-token} in it for DuckDns.org. But I cannot create one for "hub.docker.internal" as I should have to run it on docker.

Comment: if you want to use internal certificates for domains like hub.docker.internal, then you can use self-signed, but then you need to make sure the private key is added to the list of trusted certificates in each docker container.  see https://blog.container-solutions.com/adding-self-signed-registry-certs-docker-mac